# In Microsoft IE and Edge, application keeps playing sound after iframe containing it has been removed

Tags: internet-explorer, audio, iframe, canvas, microsoft-edge

I am looking at an issue where a canvas application keeps playing sound after the iframe containing it has been removed. The problem occurs in Microsoft IE and Edge, but not in Firefox or Chromium.

I don't have experience with canvas, and don't know how the canvas and the script running the application is loaded and connected, so this might not be related to the canvas itself. I don't know.

With a bit more details, one page embeds another using iframe. The embedded page has an application using canvas and playing sound. Using the developer tool, when I remove the whole iframe the canvas closes, but sound keeps playing. I have to reload the page to stop the sound.

This seems to be a bug in IE and Edge?

The web page I'm trying to fix has an iframe containing the page that has the iframe containing the application (nothing I can do about it). Is it in any way possible to access the resource that keeps playing sound, started two layers of removed iframes down?

Comment: can you post the page or code?

Comment: @Patrick I've created a basic example here: https://github.com/DanielSchaffer/msedge-audio-bug - though in my particular app, it's actually worse, since the audio never stops even when clicking. It will also create multiple instances of the audio when returning to the page, which for some reason doesn't get reproduced in the example.

Kim's solution below does indeed work though.

Answer (score 4):

We experienced a similar issue where removing an iframe from the DOM did not stop some sounds from playing. It looks as though Edge may have an issue where it wasn't dispatching the correct unload events when removing an iFrame...

Our solution was to remove the iFrame contents by clearing its `src` attribute *before* removing the actual HTMLElement from the DOM.

```
document.querySelector('#myIFrame').src = '';
```

Demo (run with Edge browser): https://embed.plnkr.co/vb08Tc1hJuVqtf4ejsJk/